# Regular expression and Requiredif mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

is there any possible way to use both on one field. RegularExpression work when SecondField value is "Yes".

```
[RequiredIf("SecondField", "Yes", ErrorMessage = "field required")]

[RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]{1}[-][0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "enter valid number i.e 385")]

public string Field{ get; set; }
```

Comment: not working basically regex work as client validation. SecondField value is 'Yes' or 'NO' regex work in both case.

Comment: the [RequiredIf] attribute is wrong, only use [Required] attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]{1}[-][0-9]*$",ErrorMessage="Enter valid number i.e 385")]
public string Field{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]
    [RegularExpression("([0-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Enter correct Phone Number")]
    [Display(Name = "PhoneNo")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
```

use this code for validating numbers (phonenumber)